# How to make a query builder in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to make a search functionality for my website with symfony.
I did this form :

```
 <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
                {{ form_start(form) }}

                {{ form_widget(form.searchText,{'attr':{'id':'search_box','class':'search_box form-control ','placeholder':'Search'}}) }}

                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">

                        <button type="button" id="search_button" class="btn btn-search"><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"
                                    aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div>
```

Next I get what user write:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
            $string = $data['searchText'];
             echo '<pre>';
            \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($string);
            exit;
            echo '</pre>';
        }
```

After I take what user wrote and I want to search in the table rows for that text and return an array in order to display it in twig.
I was thinking about making a query builder,making a select but it didn't worked .

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT u FROM ParkResortBundle:Ad u
                WHERE u. LIKE :string OR u.lastname LIKE :string')
            ->setParameter('string','%'.$string.'%')
            ->getResult();
        }
```

Comment: what didn't work?
what was the error?

Comment: I think the query is not ok..I mean it didn't show what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use `Orx` Expression in your search controller

Try adding use statement in search controller.

`use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Orx;`

then your query builder should be like `createQueryBuilder` not with `createQuery`.

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository( 'ParkResortBundle:Ad' )->createQueryBuilder( 'p' );
$qb->add( 'where',
    $qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->like( 'p.firstname', "'%{$SearchKeyword}%'" ),
        $qb->expr()->like( 'p.lastname', "'%{$SearchKeyword}%'" )
    )
);
$searchResult = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Edit 1:

To use **OrderBy** with query builder:

```
$qb = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository( 'ParkResortBundle:Ad' )->createQueryBuilder( 'p' );
    $qb->add( 'where',
        $qb->expr()->orX(
            $qb->expr()->like( 'p.firstname', "'%{$SearchKeyword}%'" ),
            $qb->expr()->like( 'p.lastname', "'%{$SearchKeyword}%'" )
        )
    );
    $qb->add('orderBy', 'p.firstname ASC');
    $searchResult = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Here is a complete list of helper methods available in [QueryBuilder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html):

Comment: It workd :) .and now How can I add an order By in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your query:

> ...
>
> WHERE u. LIKE
>
> ...

I think you missed the column name